# splice method in nested loop is removing unintenionally numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I want to find all prime numbers in a certain range. I do this with looping through the array with numbers. If a multiplier of the current number is found, then it will be removed from the array with the splice method. But some numbers will be removed like 7 and 11 which are actually prime number and some not like 8 which are not prime numbers. What is wrong in this program, I can not figure it out.

```
let list = [];
for (let i = 2; i <= 30; i++) {
  list.push(i);
}

let n = list.length - 1;

for (let prim = 0; prim <= n; prim++) {
  //multiplier is beginning at 1 for provide 2 from splice method
  for (let multiplier = 0; multiplier <= n; multiplier++) {
    //if the currentNumber is divisible by "prim" then remove it from list

    if (list[multiplier] % list[prim] == 0) {
      list.splice(multiplier, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

Comment: splice changes the length of the array and a possible index as well. solution: iterate from the end.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't quite get it, can you explain it to me a little more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splicing with deleting changes the index for the following elements.

To avoid this, you need to iterate from the end. By doing so, you need not to iterate over the index of the prime number, you are checking.

```js
let list = [];
for (let i = 2; i <= 30; i++) list.push(i);

for (let prim = 0; prim < list.length - 1; prim++) {
    for (let multiplier = list.length - 1; multiplier > prim; multiplier--) {
        if (list[multiplier] % list[prim] == 0) list.splice(multiplier, 1);
    }
    console.log(...list)
}

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So will the length of list updated every time the loop is executed?

Comment: right. this is important for both loops.

Answer (score 2):

`splice` removes the element from the list which changes the size of your `list`
you didn't check the condition for if `list[multiplier]` and `list[prim]` are the same numbers

```js
let list = [];
for (let i = 2; i <= 30; i++) {
  list.push(i);
}

for (let prim = 0; prim <list.length-1; prim++) {
  for (let multiplier = prim; multiplier <list.length; multiplier++) {
    if (list[multiplier] != list[prim] && list[multiplier] % list[prim] == 0) {
      list.splice(multiplier, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand why checking if they are the same numbers is affecting the length of the array, can you explain it please

Comment: to get the desired output you only have to add `if (list[multiplier] != list[prim] && list[multiplier] % list[prim] == 0)` line in your code but when `splice` changes the length of `list` you are running your loop for some `undefined` values. your loop will run 400+ times if you keep the fix size for loop, for the Nina Scholz answer the loop will run 70 times and for my code it will run 61 times.

Answer (score 0):

Something both simpler and faster, using [prime-lib](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib) module:

```
import {generatePrimes, stopOnValue} from 'prime-lib';

function primesRange(start: number, end: number) {
    const i = generatePrimes({start});
    return stopOnValue(i, end);
}

for (const p of primesRange(10, 30)) {
    console.log(p); //=> 11 13 17 19 23 29
}
```